# How to make splash screen fit for both landscape and portrait in ios

Tags: ios

I'm making a splash screen, but problem is, when i change to landscape , it will not fit the screen, so, how can i fix this

Here is on portrait mode:

[image]

And when switch to landscape:
[image]

So how to fix this? Thank you guy a lots

Comment: What constraints have you set, particularly for compact height traits?

Comment: weird thing is i can't set any constraints,so i don't set any constraint,  it show blank https://ibb.co/yfM8Cqg

Comment: Normally what I do is have a background image view, which deals with just the gradient (or other "background" effects) and then the transparent logo.  I then constraint the height/width of the logo to fit within the minimum requirements of the devices (I think about 300x300 is typical), so the maximum axis is 300 and you can then apply a aspect constraint if you want to, but that's up to you.  Then you can constrain the logo image view to the centre position of the view

Comment: Ah i understand but i fill the splash with whole image

Comment: You can't add constraints because you have set the layout for the image view to "Autoresizing Mask" instead of "Inferred (Autoresizing mask)"

Comment: yep, i got it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing I do is seperate the background from the logo.  As a "general" rule of thumb (for me) I try and keep the logo within about 300x300 (@ x1), but you could also make constrain the width and/or height the logo to the view's width/height.  Applying a ratio constraint would also allow you to scale the logo as a percentage of the view, while maintaining its aspect ratio (or just use "Aspect Fit" on the `UIImageView`), but every splash screen seems to want to be slightly different.

I drop a `UIImageView` onto the launch view and, making sure to turn off "Constrain to Margin" and ensure I'm referencing the `UIView` and not the "Safe Area", pin it to all the edges

[image: A place to start]

I then assign the image I want to use as the background to `UIImageView` and select "Aspect Fill" to ensure that the aspect ratio is maintained, but it will fill (or overflow) all the available area of the image view

[image: Background]

Next, I add another `UIImageView`.  Here I setup the sizing constraints for the image.  In my case, I made a square logo of 300x300px so I don't need to mess about with it and the constrain it to be centred in the launch view

[image: A logo to call my own]

Then I apply the logo image I want to use and ensure the `UIImageView` is set to "Aspect Fit" (which is now default for Xcode 11+)

[image: All those settings]

Also note that I've offset the `UIImageView`'s vertical position so it's slightly offset from the middle, don't ask me why, but it looks weird been in the middle.

You can then use the storyboard editor to explore the various devices and orientations

[image: iPhone]

[image: iPad]

You could also explore things like "size class" so you could customise how the layout changes between different device "size classes", but I think that would be overkill for something like this

Comment: Thank for your very detail answer, but i have one question, how can put image background? Can i jsut put it in image.assets?

Comment: And if i have one images, can i do that, that image contain logo, too

Comment: Yes, all the images I used came from the Assets, so you can easily select it from the `UIImageView` properties in the storyboard

Comment: *"And if i have one images, can i do that, that image contain logo, too"* - That's going to cause you issues, as the size of the image is going to want to change based on the device and orientation.  In that case, you might need at least 4 images, one for each device (iPhone/iPad) and each orientation and then make use of "trait variations" - but this is adding another level of complications

Comment: But unlucky my lead said better using image because it contain required ratio, but can you tell me how can i set to landscape by using more images? more image mean the same image but rotated, right?

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Essentially for each device and orientation, you need an image, with the correct aspect ratio for the devices (remember, you're restricted to the size classes, not the physical device, so, it's complicated).  The only choice you would have would be to allow the image to "Aspect Fill" and constrain the image view to the centre and hope it works

Comment: Thank you so much, that help me so much, if we have 100 votes, i will vote for you 